# Converting Python instance to ctypes.c_void_p

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I'm trying to convert a Python object into C void pointer so that it would be callable from C API's, however the following code doesn't seem to work
from ctypes import *

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 6
        return


foo = myclass()

data = c_void_p(foo)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
    data = c_void_p(foo)
TypeError: cannot be converted to pointer
```

I've also tried pointer() and byref(), but none of them works. How can I achieve what I'm trying to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think we need to see the use case. Are you wanting to pass the pointer to a 'C' API. Do you have an example of using it?

Comment: @quamrana Let's say I have this code in C: void bar(void* obj) { printf("%d\n", (int*)obj) }, then I would need to cast data to c_void_p in order to pass it down to this function.

Comment: Perhaps you mean `data = c_void_p(foo.val)` if the C function itself is going to recover an `int`.

Comment: @quamrana I'm trying to pass in the whole object with multiple attributes, so this method would only work with primitive types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `data = ctypes.py_object(foo)`.

`ctypes.py_object` represents the `PyObject *` type in C.